# Локальные перемные в статической перемнной c#

Tags: c#, классы, события, static

Я хочу вызвать метод для всех экземпляров класса, только чтобы в нем могли использоваться локальные переменные класса. Я знаю, что можно создать ивент и подписать на него все классы и вызывать когда это нужно, но есть ли решение менее трудозатратное?

```
class Prog
{
    private int valu = 1;

    static void statMethod()
    {
        valu = 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так сделайте список этих классов и пробегайте циклом по нему, вызывая нужный метод.

Comment: А по поводу статики - вам так или иначе надо проинициализировать класс для того, что бы добраться до его не статичных переменных. Либо делайте их тоже статиками, либо используйте например синглтон.